# Open Source Proxy Library for .Net

Tags: .net, proxy

I'm looking for a open source .Net HTTP proxy library. Basically I want to develop something like Fiddler (so much lighter with less features).

Comment: "closed as too localized by Will" Always this man is closing a great topics whithout any real argument, @will, did you noticed +6 upvote there(top left)? that means that the question is NOT too localized(as you reported). I don't want to live in this world anymore...... :3

Comment: @smarty you're right.  Should have been closed as "not constructive," as we normally close questions that attract link-only answers and spam (which you can't see; you're welcome).  For more info on why we don't do shopping questions, please visit [meta].

Comment: @SmartyTwiti also, you'll note that its *four years old* and a whole **six people** found it helpful enough to upvote.  Only been viewed 2k times.  But since I don't want you to jump off a bridge, I've changed the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the Mentalis Proxy at work:
http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

It's not been touched for a while so there may be a few bugs.

Licence details are here: http://www.mentalis.org/site/license.qpx

Answer (score 7):

Mentalis doesn't handle non-ASCII very well.  The core proxy engine of Fiddler is called "FiddlerCore," now available as a .NET class library: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/

Answer (score 1):

There is [URLRewriter.NET](http://urlrewriter.sourceforge.net/), a free open-source component for IIS/ASP.NET.

As the name suggests, it's an URL rewriting component, but it has **also proxying capabilities**. With a simple line like this in the configuration file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.testsiteXY.com$1 [P]
```

you could easily use it as proxy.

Comment: I'm looking for a client-side proxy library, something user will install can will see their HTTP Requests and responses.