# Any resource/codes on how fiddler works?

Tags: http, redirect, request, fiddler

I need to track http/url requests & redirects from a windows forms application using C#. It should handle both IE & firefox. Not sure if Fiddler is open-source but if i'm not mistaken, it's written using .NET. Sample codes or online articles on how to listen to http/url requests & redirects will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Leon, could you mark the relevant answer as accepted?

Answer (score 17):

Fiddler works as standard HTTP [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). There is no magic here. See HTTP protocol for details. In both IE/Firefox, you need to set Fiddler (or your custom program) as proxy, and then browser will use it for all outgoing requests. Proxy is responsible for forwarding request to correct server, and returning response. Proxies are typically used for 1) caching, 2) controlling access (and avoiding firewalls), 3) debugging.

See also [Open Source Proxy Library for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311181/open-source-proxy-library-for-net) for [.NET proxy library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/) (just quick googling... I have no experience with it).

Comment: is there any information out there that I can use to build my own HTTP proxy like `fiddler`?where to start? do I have to write it in c++?

Answer (score 14):

You'd probably be interested in the new FiddlerCore library: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore