# How can I read all the network data sent to another process in C# or Java?

Tags: c#, networking, process, monitor

I want to make a program in either C# or Java that can read all of the network data sent to another program I have open. I want to then save this in a log file. Can anyone give me some suggestions as to how I can achieve this? (I would prefer to use C#)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Http Proxy to capture the network traffic (assuming it's http), just as the popular tool `Fiddler` does.  Take a look here: [Any resource/codes on how fiddler works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549520/any-resource-codes-on-how-fiddler-works)